# Add methods to Higher Order Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From what I understand, HOCs in ReactJS add props to your decorated component, but I want to add methods that can also act on the `state`.
As an example, I generally never call `this.setState()` without checking `this.isMounted()` first. In essence, I want:

```
export default ComposedComponent => class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
    static displayName = "BaseComponent";

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

//------> I want this method to be available to any ComposedComponent
//------> And it has to act upon the state of ComposedComponent
    updateState(obj) {
        if (this.isMounted() && obj) {
            this.setState(obj);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <ComposedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />
        )
    }
}
```

Say I want to decorate my component `Home`. So I'd just return it as `export default BaseComponent(Home)`.

But `this.updateState()` is not available inside `Home` class. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I had spent too much time on this, so I hope this answer could help somebody out as well. Short answer: add the method in your decorator to `props`, then bind it in your decorated class' constructor.

Here is the code:

```
export default ComposedComponent => class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
    static displayName = "BaseComponent";

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Note how I am adding this to state
        // This will be passed as a prop to your composed component
        this.state = {
            updateState: this.updateState
        }
    }


    updateState(obj) {
        this.setState(obj);
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <ComposedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />
        )
    }
}
```

And here is an example of a class that would use it (I'm using `ES7` for simplicity):

```
@BaseComponent
class Home extends React.Component {
    static displayeName = 'Home';

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // And here I am binding to it
        this.updateState = this.props.updateState.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hi</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do the same thing. I think I am going to just call the functions from a extra prop with multiple functions